# How do i use concatenation JavaScript

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I'm following a course about JavaScript and i'm stuck for days in one question.

Use the strings available in the given variables to produce and print the famous Shakesperean quote (remember: spaces are characters too).

My code for now is:

```js
var sentence1 = 'to be';
var sentence2 = 'or not';
console.log(sentence1 + ' ' + (sentence2));
```

And the output says:

> > > > Code is incorrect
> > > >         You should chain the five string concatenations

I've tried to use brackets on the second sentence but it didn't work out. What i don't understand is how to chain the five strings as the output is asking me. Anybody any suggestions to solve this mystery?

Comment: Try this console.log(sentence1 + ' ' + sentence2);

Comment: what is "*five string*"?

Comment: It should be `sentence1 + ' ' + sentence2 +  ' ' + sentence1` to get the phrase `to be or not to be`

Comment: A little detail would help a long way . Are there 5 strings in the question that needs to be concatenated?

Comment: Thanks Adiga. Now i see what i did wrong and how close i was to solving this question. Did completely miss the double sentence1.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
console.log(sentence1 + ' ' + sentence2 + ' ' + sentence1);
```

Although since the error talks about chaining maybe using `concat()` is what they're after.

```
sentence1.concat( ... )
```